# How to reproduce AsyncTask from Android in Java pure code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to reproduce the same logical that Android's AsyncTask follows in Java pure code.

To do that I have created the abstract class AsyncTask implementing my IAsynTask that basically calls onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute, also I have created the method execute where the magic happens.

So to use that in my login process, for example, I've created LoginTask class extending AsyncTask, but unlike I had imagined the implemetation of onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute doesn't look to be mandatory. What am I doing wrong?

Inteface:

```
public interface IAsyncTask {

    public void onPreExecute();
    public void doInBackground();
    public void onPostExecute();

}
```

Class:

```
public abstract class AsyncTask implements IAsyncTask{

    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    public void doInBackground(){

    }

    public void onPostExecute() {

    }

    public void execute() {

        onPreExecute();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                doInBackground();

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onPostExecute();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**[EDITED]**

With my questions about javafx I have noticed that many newer developers are facing problem managing Threads. I would like to share what I have done to simplify my life about managing threads on javafx. I've created an AsyncTask class based on AsyncTask from Android that basically do the same of Android's in a humble but effective way. You can find more information about it on [Github project](https://github.com/victorlaerte/javafx-asynctask)

Comment: Why don't see sources of Android?

Comment: Android is open source, you can just go and copy the code...

Comment: Here it is: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated that I want to reproduce, as you can see my class is very simple

Comment: What do you mean by the implementation doesn't look to be mandatory?  I'm confused by what your problem is.  Everything looks like its being called.  Not sure what Platform.runLater is doing, but the rest looks fine.

Comment: Shouldn't onPostExecute happen on the main thread, rather than on the same thread as doInBackground()? I thought onPostExecute was what let you manipulate the UI once your AsyncTask finished executing.

Comment: You probably want to look at the source code for `Looper` and `Handler` in android. From my understanding AsyncTask is just a front for a Handler which in tern relies on Looper.  Your implementation will most likely be based on a `SynchronousQueue<Runnable>`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Platform is the way to run in main thread using javafx. And about mandatory, is because the netbeans doesn't say to implement the methods, if I don't implent it doesn't return any error

Comment: @ShaquilHansford is exactly what Platform.runlater is doing, running onPost in the main thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry if I didn't can explain what exactly I wanted, but after you see my code you guys will understand. I just added a abstrac identifier in my methods and got what I wanted. It could seem like a newbie issue, but I think it can be used to simplify some simple operations without directly manage threads.

What I did to reproduce a simple AsyncTask using Java and Javafx code:

create a abstract class AsyncTask

```
public abstract class AsyncTask {

    abstract void onPreExecute();

    abstract void doInBackground();

    abstract void onPostExecute();

    public void execute() {

        onPreExecute();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                doInBackground();

                //Platform.runLater is a javafx code that executes onPost in Main Thread.
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onPostExecute();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Extend it from our worker class

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    void onPreExecute() {

        //Some code to preexecute in Main Thread
        System.out.println("OnPreExecute - Main Thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
    }

    @Override
    void doInBackground() {

        //Some code to execute in background thread as internet requests
        System.out.println("doInBackground - Main Thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
    }

    @Override
    void onPostExecute() {

        //Some code to execute in Main thread after background process has done, like update a view
        System.out.println("onPostExecute - Main Thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());        
    }

}
```

To call it you can do:

```
LoginTask taskTest = new LoginTask();
taskTest.execute();
```

and your log will be:

```
OnPreExecute - Main Thread: true
doInBackground - Main Thread: false
onPostExecute - Main Thread: true
```

Comment: But what was the reason you couldn't just use AsyncTask? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: because it's not an Android Project hahaha

Comment: @VictorOliveira `AsyncTask` is just Java code. Good post by the way.

Comment: `AsyncTask` source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java.

Answer (score -1):

AsyncTask is at its core, a thread. It is a thread that starts in another arbitrary thread (but usually the main), does its task, and then delegates a post task to the thread that spawned it (as I said, usually the main thread).

The problem you are going to run into while working on this project is the Handler class that handles(!) this thread delegation feature I mentioned above. Handler is a core feature of android allowing from non-main thread task delegation to the thread it was created in. For you to implement a sort of Java AsyncTask, you will need add in a thread delegation API that in essence works the same as Handler.

Comment: I should add that since Android has its own inter-process communication mechanic, which AsyncTask heavily depends on, you need to replicate the whole IPC in your project to achieve that.

Comment: Thread delegation should not be too difficult.  The basic principle is that all the "main" thread does is to sit on a loop processing `.run()` on Runnable objects in a queue. Java has in built queues which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey could you reference the documentation on the IPC ability / requirement of an async task. I thought they only worked within the same process.

Comment: AsyncTask is not a thread.  AsyncTask is queued into a single, or multithread pool for execution. AsyncTask is more like a Runnable. The difference is small, but thought I'd mention it.